# IOS Newstand app

Tags: ios, iphone, newsstand-kit

I have a plan to create a news stand app for selling our clients magazines.They already have an online subscription option for printable copies on their website.My question here is

If a user purchased one year subscription for printable copies from website can we give an option to read same magazine from new stand if he login using same credentials in the website? is this possible?

Help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you will need to show a login screen to authenticate the user, and make sure that you offer In App subscription price that is equal or cheaper to the price that you're offering it on other platforms.

Check out this [Newsstand FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2280/_index.html) from Apple.